# Rewiring protools and ableton live to cut sound for picture

Tags: pro-tools, ableton-live

Hi
I want to create Tron like sound effects for video in
 protools by manipulating the sound layers. I want to send the later of sounds to
Another sampler like plugin and manipulate it.

I tried with Reason but it only supports midi and not audio.
So can I create my layers in Protools (I'm quite familiar with protools)
And some how send the audio in realtime to Ableton(not familiar with using it but aware of its capabilities) and using Ableton's plugin chain Manipulate the sounds in Ableton and return in protools.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you had enough outputs and inputs on your audio interface, you could hard-patch it to your liking.

If you're trying to do it without hardware, you are looking for a software with routing capabilities like Jack (http://www.jackosx.com/). Which version of ProTools are you on? You can't do it on the older versions of PT, but with 9 and 10 you might have a chance. I haven't tried it but you could try to use Jack Pilot to hack the software outputs.

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=93414

Answer (score 1):

According the topic here http://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=143804 it is not possible to use Rewire Slave as effect processor.

You will be able to use Ableton as dam good sampler, but not as effect chain.

Answer (score 0):

Dual-system would be your best bet ie. output audio from one computer into the interface of another. We used to do that all the time in film school to record half-speed playback from one pro-tools rig to another. Soundflower might work as well...it's an app by the guys and gals at Cycling74 that basically operates like a virtual patchbay, and it's free. Pro-Tools is not really open to that type of hacking but you can find some third party apps like AntiMatter and Max that better facilitate that type of workflow.

Anyway, dual-system or Soundflower. Good luck to you, and watch your ears!

Answer (score 0):

Found something similar for Windows, as im on windows7... its called Virtual Audio Cable
http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm

yet to try it with Protools and ableton.